# many to many relationships to itself with additional fields in code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, code-first

I have this entity:

```
public class Content
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Test { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

and I want to create many-to-many relationship to itself with additional fields in code-first like the following image:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Im not too sure what you mean, in the above diagram you have 2 1-many relationships with content, what would you like this to look like?

Comment: this is very simple it means that each content can be related to many contents if you have many-to-many relationship you can break it to two 1-many relationships it means that. assume I have a news website and each news can be related to one or many other news.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like the following:

```
public class Content
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ContentLink> OtherContents { get; set; }
}

public class ContentLink
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Content Lhs{ get; set; }
    public Content Rhs{ get; set; }
    //other stuff
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Content>().
    HasMany(c => c.OtherContents).WithRequired(c=>c.Lhs);
modelBuilder.Entity<ContentLink>().
    HasRequired(c => c.Rhs).WithMany();
```

NOTE: the above will only allow you to traverse resources this entity links to not other entities who link to you

Check out my post on nav properties here for more details: http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/7/17/entity_framework-navigation_property_basics_with_code_first

Comment: this code is not following my scenario, it means that each content can be related to many ContentRelation. I want to join each content to other contents.

Comment: @MehrdadBahrainy like this?

Comment: If you want metadata on the link you will need to create a link table and put the metadata in there. When you are doing this you cant use a many to many relationship in EF, instead use 2 1->many relationships

Comment: yes you are right, I cant solve this problem with many to many relationship in EF, finally I have to use 2 one to many relations ;) thank you ;)